# Laravel package alias present in app() but still gives class not found

Tags: laravel, alias

I can see my alias present in app aliases array:

```
    dd(app()); // ... "Me\Package\Facades\PHPFile" => "PHPFile"
```

using that same full name works

```
    dd(
        \Me\Package\Facades\PHPFile::load('app/User.php')
    );
```

BUT trying to use the registered alias:

```
    dd(
        \PHPFile::load('app/User.php')
    );
    // Error: Class 'PHPFile' not found
```

Even though it was registered in `app()`! Any ideas whats going on here?

In my package composer.json:

```
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": [],
        "providers": [
            "Me\\Package\\MyServiceProvider"
        ],
        "aliases": {
            "PHPFile": "Me\\Package\\Facades\\PHPFile"
        }            
    }
},
```

Also tried adding this in my serviceproviders register method:

```
$this->app->alias('PHPFile','Me\Package\Facades\PHPFile');
```

Comment: the aliases you are seeing aren't the ones for aliasing classes outside the container via the autoload system, the alias you are seeing might be for aliasing a binding by another name ... how did you add your 'alias'?

Comment: Updated with composer.json where I would like to automatically register my aliases if possible

Comment: your composer.json seems okay (probably dont need the `dont-discover`), i assume package discovery has ran?

Comment: The serviceprovider is running, but my package is not listed in 'Discovered package'-list. Do I need something more in my host app composer.json? Right now I only have autoload -> psr-4 -> Me\Package => packages/Me/Package/src

Comment: if it is a package it should have its own composer.json and be required of the main application... if you are just including this namespace in your main composer.json then there is no package to discover because it isn't handled by composer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Host application composer.json

add

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "/full/path/to/packages/Me/Package"
    }
],
```

Then install with `composer require "me/package @dev"`

Thanks to @lagbox for spotting my error in comments